# Is there exist in a market some usb->ethernet->wifi combo dongle?

Tags: ssl, wifi, ethernet, usb, eap

I have a USB-ended device which I want to connect to Enterprise Wireless network (EAP/TLS via FreeRadius). Is there any device in a market which can act as a WiFi client with EAP/TLS possibility?

Now this device connected to the network via USB-to-Ethernet adapter in a wall-mounted RJ45.
Furthermore, is there any combo device in a market which can act as USB-to-Ethernet from one side and in the same time as Wireless client on the other side?
details for what I am mention is on the followed picture:

[image]

Comment: What is the point of having Ethernet in here? It is not necessary. And USB WiFi clients already exist and can be purchased with pocket coins.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, the point is a configuring of a WiFi client from inside the device. device can configure ethernet. But can not see and configure Wifi

Comment: That sounds like a software problem.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, this is a hardware problem, due to no OS inside the device

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a wireless access point (WAP) with client mode. It's the same device you'd use to connect a wired device to WLAN.

Configure that WAP to connect to the Wi-Fi network and bridge that to its Ethernet interface. Make sure the WAP you select supports the authentication method of your Wi-Fi (WPA2/3-PSK or -ENT).